# set style to only first element created with *ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular, ngfor

I am using the follwing code to display some number of `*` characters

```
  <div *ngFor="let line of lines;let i=index">*</div>
```

I would like to set a margin only to the first one. I want the margin to be bound to a `marginVar` variable inside coresponding `.ts` file.

This is how I would set margin to all of the elements.

```
[style.margin-left.px]="marginVar"
```

How can I apply it to only the first element created with `*ngFor`?

Comment: Did you try using ngIf?

Comment: I have though about it, but I am not sure how to wrap [style.margin-left.px]="marginVar" inside ngIf directive

Comment: you can try using ngStyle and ngIf together

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ngFor` provides `first`

```
<div *ngFor="let line of lines;let i=index; first as isFirst"
    [style.margin-left.px]="isFirst ? marginVar : 0">*</div>
```

or using CSS

```
<div *ngFor="let line of lines;let i=index; first as isFirst"
    [class.first]="isFirst">*</div>
```

For all `*ngFor` variables see

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to using css classes then it is straightforward:

```
[class.first]="i === 0"
```

Otherwise play with `ngIf` (`ngIfThen`/`ngIfElse`).